# riddle: "I can fly / without wings..."

Tags: riddle, word

A riddle:

> I can fly
> without wings
> I can cry
> without eyes
> What am I?

What is the answer?

Comment: Can you tell us where this came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are

> Cloud

> Cloud "flies" (without wings) in the air and "cries" (without eyes) when raining